# Problem with running a tensorflow-based script on multiple GPUs of a cluster

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I want to train a 3D model based on tensorflow. I'm using a node in a cluster with 8 GPUs (Geforce GTX 1080 ti, with 1045 MB memory for each one). My inputs are 3D CT images. When I reduce the image dimensions to 64×64×64 the model is trained appropriately. However, the following error is shown when the input dimensions are 128×128×128.

```
2023-10-18 07:08:18.796407: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:497] *****************************************___________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_codes/my_model.py", line 419, in <module>
    model_unet3D.fit(x_train, y_train,
  File "/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 98, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

I have used "tf.distribute" for running on multiple GPUs.

```
# Tensorflow Distributed Strategy (for running on multiple GPUs)
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    input_shape=(n_slices, width, height, n_channels)
    model_unet3D = unet3D(input_shape)
    
    model_unet3D.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-4),
                       loss= tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), #dice_plus_focal_loss,
                       metrics=['acc',mean_iou, dice_coef],
                         )
    model_unet3D.summary()
    
    checkpoint_path = "/model/my_model.ckpt"
    my_callbacks = [
        tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('train_log_3D.csv', separator=",", append=False),
        tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, save_best_only=True) #save_freq=5, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1
        #tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard()
    ]
    
    model_unet3D.fit(x_train, y_train,
                     validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                     epochs=20,
                     batch_size=1,
                     verbose=1,
                     callbacks = my_callbacks)
```

How can I resolve the problem?

I have tried increasing the number of nodes and GPUs, but the same error appeared. I have also changed the batch size, but the memory limitation still remains even for a batch size of 1.

**Update:**

I have modified the code by using a custom data generator as follows:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, data, labels, batch_size, shuffle=True):
        self.data = data
        self.labels = labels
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.data))
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.data) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        start_idx = index * self.batch_size
        end_idx = (index + 1) * self.batch_size
        batch_data = self.data[start_idx:end_idx]
        batch_labels = self.labels[start_idx:end_idx]
        # Load and preprocess your 3D image data here if necessary
        # e.g., using NumPy, PIL, or other image processing libraries
        return batch_data, batch_labels

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
            
batch_size = 1  # Adjust the batch size as needed
train_gen = DataGenerator(x_train, y_train, batch_size)
val_gen = DataGenerator(x_test, y_test, batch_size, shuffle=False)

model.fit(train_gen,
                 validation_data=val_gen,
                 epochs=20,
                 verbose=1,
                 )
```

Now, I have encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_codes/model.py", line 468, in <module>
    model_unet3D.fit(train_gen,
  File "/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Graph execution error
```